# Omniauth with Linkedin in Rails to Post Updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api, omniauth

I have an application using OmniAuth for authenticating with a variety of social networking services (including Linkedin) and want to post updates. I have the following information on a user from omniauth:

```
linkedin_verifier: ****
linkedin_token: *****
linkedin_secret: *****
linkedin_url: http://www.linkedin.com/pub/*****
```

But can't figure out how to use it to post. I've taken a look at: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin, but it requires a request token and request secret (I seem to only have the response token and response secret) that I don't get from omniauth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried authorize_from_access using the token and secret you get after omniauth?

client = LinkedIn::Client.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')
client.authorize_from_access(linkedin_token, linkedin_secret)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  If the user authenticated previously using OmniAuth, you should have the account information in your database.  For linkedin_token , linkedin_secret, use: User.authentications.find_by_provider('linkedin').token / secret (assuming you are using a model similar to the Omniauth Railscast).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When using that code it redirects me to: `auth/failure?message=invalid_response` – Without that specific code I'm authorized fine, which means the code in your answer is causing the redirect, although I'm not sure how it knows to redirect to that specific URL as it's from OmniAuth. – Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

from the link (https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) I found this,

You need to get your api keys first, create a client with them and then you will get your request token and response.

---

`#get your api keys at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer`

client = LinkedIn::Client.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')

rtoken = client.request_token.token

rsecret = client.request_token.secret

Comment: Even if I'm already using OmniAuth to authenticate? I don't want to ask the users twice...